# H2 database return empty query result in REST api

Tags: java, gradle, tomcat, jersey

I have REST API which get data from H2 database using Hibernate.  I added some data to database, but Query with select return empty list from database. I don't understand why the
query returns empty result in one case, but it returns correct data from main method. How to fix it?

```
@Path("/drones")
public class DroneResource {

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public List<Employee> getEmployee() {
        EmployeeDAO dao = new EmployeeDAO();
         **// Return empty list **
        List employees = dao.getEmployees();
        return employees;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EmployeeDAO dao = new EmployeeDAO();
       **// Return correct data from db **
       List employees = dao.getEmployees(); 

    }
}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory name="hibernateSessionFactory">
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:h2:./h2db;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">admin</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">admin</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.server_timezone">UTC</property>

        <mapping class="com.gitlab.olorini.test.Employee"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd"
         version="5.0">
    <display-name>Drones manager</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Example API</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.gitlab.olorini.web.services.endpoints</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Example API</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Class of db entity

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column
    private String name;
    @Column
    private int age;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

}
```

DAO

```
public class EmployeeDAO {

   public List<Employee> getEmployees(){
        Session session = SessionUtil.getSession();
        Query query = session.createQuery("from Employee");
        List<Employee> employees =  query.list();
        session.close();
        return employees;
    }
}
```

```
public class SessionUtil {

    private static SessionUtil instance=new SessionUtil();
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public static SessionUtil getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }

    private SessionUtil(){
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
    }

    public static Session getSession(){
        Session session =  getInstance().sessionFactory.openSession();

        return session;
    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
}

group 'com.github.olorini'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
project.webAppDirName = 'web'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'lib'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.6.12.Final'
    implementation 'javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.1.Final'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2:2.1.214'
    implementation 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-bundle:1.19.4'
    implementation 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:1.19.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Project structure

Comment: Try by creating transaction object then execute your query.

Comment: Tried to do the query in transaction. It doesn't help.

Comment: Session session = SessionUtil.getSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        Query query = session.createQuery("from Employee");
        List<Employee> employees =  query.list();
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
        return employees;

Return empty list (

Comment: Can you please post the table name from which you are getting data and hibernate query which generated by hibernate.